# '.' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Quando tento usar o comando **./configure** no cmd do windows para instalar o freetds recebo a mensagem

'.' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Qual a finalidade desse `./configure`, já que `./configure` não é um comando padrão do linux então encontrar um equivalente no windows sem ter uma especificação precisa do que você quer fazer é impossível.

Comment: Instalaçao do Freetds:

   $ ./configure --help
   $ ./configure
   $ make
   $ make install

Comment: Para que o freetds no windows??? Ha uma versão windows do FreeTDS https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/ mas eu acho desnescessaria.

Comment: Já baixei mas como faço para instalar? Preciso do FreeTDS para usar a biblioteca ctds do python

Comment: Esse zip contém todo os binários do FreeTDS(*.exe, *.sys e *.dll). São os mesmos arquivos que obteria usando o CMake , como indicado aqui https://www.freetds.org/userguide/osissues.htm, ou baixando os componentes individualmente daqui https://ci.appveyor.com/project/FreeTDS/freetds/history . Descompacte o conteúdo em uma pasta. Haverão duas sub pastas, cada uma tem o sua prórpria  pasta `bin`, edite variável de ambiente path adicionando os caminhos a essas duas pastas

Comment: Mas quando eu baixo e tento rodar o pip install ctds  da o erro:     LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'sybdb.lib'

Comment: Desculpe o link que passei está incompleto, tente esse: https://ci.appveyor.com/api/buildjobs/5tx4vwl7vkfdkxn8/artifacts/vs2017_64-master.zip  .Se olhar em `vs2017_64-master\bin` vai estar lá o `sysdb.dll` e em `\vs2017_64-master\lib` vai encontrar `sysdb.lib`

Comment: Essa versão está completa mas agora deu o seguinte erro:     build\lib.win32-3.8\_tds.cp38-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 58 unresolved externals
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1120